# ngAfterViewInit is not getting called while navigating between pages

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular6, ionic4

Cart Page

```js
import { Component, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit, OnInit, AfterContentInit, ChangeDetectorRef, } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router'
import { StorageService } from '../data/storage.service';
import { DataProviderService } from '../data/data-provider.service';
import * as _ from 'lodash';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-cart',
  templateUrl: './cart.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cart.page.scss'],
})
export class CartPage implements AfterViewInit, AfterContentInit, OnDestroy, OnInit {

  cartItems = [];
  totalAmount = 0;

  constructor(public cart: StorageService, private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef, public dataProvider: DataProviderService, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }



  ngOnInit() {

    console.log("Init callled")
  }

  async ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log("Lets check!!");
    console.log("\n\n\n\nthis is init func");
  }
}
```

Details page

```js
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit, ChangeDetectorRef, ChangeDetectionStrategy, AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { DataProviderService } from '../data/data-provider.service';
import { UtilsService } from '../data/utils.service';
import { StorageService } from '../data/storage.service';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router'
import * as _ from 'lodash';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-details',
  templateUrl: './details.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./details.page.scss'],
})
export class DetailsPage implements AfterViewInit, AfterContentInit, OnDestroy {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef, public dataProvider: DataProviderService, public utils: UtilsService, public cart: StorageService, private router: Router) {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
   console.log("Details page view Init");
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    console.log("I'm destroying details!!");
  }
  ngAfterContentInit() {
    console.log("View content is triggered");
  }
```

Router Module

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule' },
  { path: 'details/:category/:id', loadChildren: './details/details.module#DetailsPageModule',runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'},
  { path: 'products/:category', loadChildren: './products/products.module#ProductsPageModule' },
  { path: 'products/:category/:market', loadChildren: './products/products.module#ProductsPageModule' },
  { path: 'reports', loadChildren: './reports/reports.module#ReportsPageModule' },
  { path: 'news', loadChildren: './news/news.module#NewsPageModule' },
  { path: 'buy', loadChildren: './buy/buy.module#BuyPageModule' },
  { path: 'Offers', loadChildren: './offers/offers.module#OffersPageModule' },
  { path: 'cart', loadChildren: './cart/cart.module#CartPageModule' , runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'},
  { path: 'checkout', loadChildren: './checkout/checkout.module#CheckoutPageModule' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

When I load the page for the first time, it calls the function `ngAfterViewInit`. But when I navigate to some other route and come back, `ngAfterViewInit` is not getting called.

`ngOnInit` won't get called if we reload the page. So I'm using `ngAfterViewInit` which is not helping. Is this expected behavior?

How can I execute a function on each time user navigates to the page?

Comment: Are you changing whole component using route? or your component is steady for both the page?

Comment: Check if ngOnDestroy is called when you navigate to another route. If not then it means that your component is still loaded. Check your routing configuration - maybe you have nested routes?

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers, The use case is, I'll add a record to local storage. when I come back to this page, need to read the storage and repaint that. Components are not the same both pages.

Comment: @Shahar, For this page, ngDestroy is not getting called. When I navigate from the previous page, it calls destroy. While navigating to some other page, ngDestroy is not getting called for this page. 

I attached routerEvent in app component. How can I trigger ngDestroy manually?

Comment: @SantoshHegde you're not supposed to call ngOnDestroy manually. It's part of the component lifecycle and called automatically whenever the component is destroyed.

Comment: @shahar, What's the fix/work around for this issue?

Comment: @SantoshHegde hard to say without looking at the project code, but I would start by checking why your CartPage component is not destroyed when you switch to other pages. Try to check if other pages' components are destroyed when you switch to other views, and then find out where's the difference. If you can show the code where you manage the routes that might help.

Comment: @Shahar Added more details and code

Answer (score 0):

you can subscribe to router events https://angular.io/guide/router#router-events

Comment: There is no mention of router events anymore on the link